# Scope of variable in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I've got this function

```
function parseLink(link) {
    var product;
    request(link, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            // title
            var title = $('h1').text();
            if (!title)
                var title = $('title').text();

            var description = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');

            product = new Product(link.trim(), title.trim(), description.trim());
        }
    });
    console.log(product);
    return product;
}
```

And I don't understand why when I do **console.log(product)** outside of the request call, I've got **undefinded** but inside, I can see my product.

I learn lot of things about scopes in javascript and I don't understand, causse I defined **product** in the top function.
I need to return this variable for get it in another function, if do the return inside request I've got of course an undefined so I need to do that outside...
Thank you

Comment: Because you did not assign a value to your variable `product` in the top function and `console.log()` don't wait assignment from the request function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Where is your `request` function defined?

Comment: Thanks but I need to return the value like `var linkParsed = parseLink(data[0]);`z

Answer (score 0):

javascript does not run the code like `c` or `php` where you can be sure that the next line of code runs when the previous is ready. In your case `request` is an asynchronous function so the two lines

```
console.log(product);
return product;
```

are mostly run before your `request` function is ready. In that case you can not just return some value from your `parseLink` function. You have two possibilities here:

1. use promises:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
2. use a callback:

like this:

```
function parseLink(link, callback) {
    var product;
    request(link, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            // title
            var title = $('h1').text();
            if (!title)
                var title = $('title').text();

            var description = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');

            product = new Product(link.trim(), title.trim(), description.trim());
            callback(product);
        }
    });
}
```

and you run the code like

```
parseLink('http://...', function(product) { /* do something with the product */ });
```

ps: the use of callbacks is a lot easier imo, but in some cases you can to separate the scope for example if you run it in a `for` loop

Comment: Thank you, I call parseLink from another function. I want to do something like that in this function: `var linkParsed = parseLink(data[0]);`

Comment: Like I have written it is not possible to directly return a value from an asynchronous function. At the end of my answer is an example with a callback function. Miguel also provided an example with a promise

Comment: What about C? You can pass a pointer-to-function as an argument in a call and you won't have an idea whether the function has been called by the time this call returns.

Comment: Thanks but I need to return the value like `var linkParsed = parseLink(data[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

`request` is an asynchronous call so this procedure gets pushed to the event queue which will run once the current call stack has finished. `console.log` prints `undefined` because that is the default value for unassigned variables.

You must use callbacks or promises if you need to return the value from the asynchronous call. Here's an example using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function parseLink(link) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(link, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error);

      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return reject(new Error('Not OK'));
      }

      var $ = cheerio.load(body);

      var title = $('h1').text() || $('title').text();
      var description = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
      var product = new Product(link.trim(), title.trim(), description.trim());

      resolve(product);
    });
  });
}

parseLink('http://example.com')
  .then(product => {
    console.log(product);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to return the value like `var linkParsed = parseLink(data[0]);`

Comment: @Tech you'll need to do a synchronous request but it's highly not recommended https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request